# Find the maximum profit when selling theatre seats

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, sliding-window

In a theatre show there are N seats [1,2,3,...N] each set at a different price such that the ith ticket costs A[i]. People come in group and want to sit together. The indexes of the array B indicate the respective group sizes. With an optimal seating plan, determine the maximum profit the owner can make.

Eg:

N=6;

A = [9, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3]

B = [2, 3]

Ans: The array A can be divided such that 9 + 2 + 5 = 16 and 2+3=5. Therefore the cost of the ticket sold can be 16+5=21

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you facing an issue?

Comment: What are the limits on N, the prices, and the group sizes?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I am thinking of applying sliding window approach but i have no clue how to do that for more than one window sliding while maintaining the max value for each.

Comment: @user3386109 you can assume its not that big of numbers, I just needed one approach to solve this kind of problems and I would appreciate your help.

Comment: One approach is to try all of the permutations of array B. In the example, there are only two permutations: [2,3] and [3,2]. Then try putting the first group at every valid position. A valid position is one that leaves enough room for the other groups. A sliding window can be used to quickly compute the profit for each position. Memoization can be used because there will be common subproblems to solve.

Comment: @user3386109 The larger groups will always be more profitable to place first. However, in my solution I did not think to leave room for other groups. Good thinking

Comment: @Fire'NLightnin' If I understand what you're saying, then I have to disagree. The counter-example is `A=[9,9,0,9,9,0,1,1,1,1,1]` with group sizes `B=[5,2,2]`. If you place the 5 group first, and maximize its profit, you'll end up with `[9,9,0,9,9], [1,1], [1,1]` for a profit of 40. But the optimal answer is `[9,9], [9,9], [1,1,1,1,1]` for a profit of 41. In short, I don't think there's any greedy algorithm that's optimal.

Comment: Sounds to me like we'll want to do dynamic programming. I'd probably still sort the array B in descending order so that you can exit early from an "infeasible" solution.